# Error for file validation then using symfony validator as standalone class in my php project

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I work on a PHP project and implement Symfony validation as a standalone class. Everything is ok, but when I try to validate the file I have an error and I don't know how to solve it. Can somebody help me?

In my functions I have

```
function processFile()
{
    global $request;
    
    $file = $request->files->get('file');
    $validateFile = [
        'file' => new Assert\File([
            'maxSize' => '64M',
            'maxSizeMessage' => 'The file is too big',
            'mimeTypes' => ['pdf' => 'application/pdf'],
            'mimeTypesMessage' => 'The format is incorrect, only PDF allowed',
            'uploadNoFileErrorMessage' => 'No file was selected'
        ]),
    ];
       
    
    $validator = Validation::createValidator();
    $violations = $validator->validate($arrayData, $validateFile);
    if (0 !== count($violations)) {
        $errorMessages = getErrorMessage($violations);
    
        require_once(TEMPLATES . 'processFileForm.php');
        die();
    }
   

    /**
      * @param $violations
      * @return array
      */
    function getErrorMessage($violations): array
    {
        $accessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
        $errorMessages = array();
        foreach ($violations as $violation) {
            $accessor->setValue($errorMessages, ($violation->getPropertyPath()), $violation->getMessage());
        
        }
        
        return $errorMessages;
    }
```

If I dump the violations I see the error message for not correct format and so on for file validation, but it gives me an error on

> Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\InvalidPropertyPathException: The property path should not be empty.